# PySpark error when getting shape of Dataframe using Pandas on spark API

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, pyspark-pandas

My folder structure is currently this
|- logger
|--- __init__.py
|--- logger.py
|- another_package
|--- __init__.py
|--- module1.py
|- models
|--- model1
|------ main.py
|------ model1_utilities.py

The spark context and session are started in main.py. main.py calls model1_utilities.py like this:

```
results = function_a(params)
logger.info('Calculation completed')
num_rows = results.shape[0]
```

I have a log statement within the model1_utilities.py as well which says
`logger.info("Completed function call")`
just before the return statement

Now this is my error:

```
INFO:main:Completed function call                               
INFO:main:Calculation completed
22/06/16 15:04:36 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 451.0 (TID 908)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user1/Desktop/code/models/model1/model1_utilities.py", line 3, in <module>
    import logger
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logger'

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:555)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:508)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage87.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage87.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
22/06/16 15:04:36 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 451.0 (TID 908) (10.0.0.162 executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user1/Desktop/code/models/model1/model1_utilities.py", line 3, in <module>
    import logger
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logger'

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:555)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:508)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage87.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage87.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

22/06/16 15:04:36 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 451.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
ERROR:main:Program did not finish successfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user1/Desktop/code/models/model1/main.py, line 174, in <module>
    num_alerts = results.shape[0]
  File "/Users/user1/opt/anaconda3/envs/work/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/pandas/frame.py", line 7445, in shape
    return len(self), len(self.columns)
  File "/Users/user1/opt/anaconda3/envs/work/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/pandas/frame.py", line 11909, in __len__
    return self._internal.resolved_copy.spark_frame.count()
  File "/Users/user1/opt/anaconda3/envs/work/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 680, in count
    return int(self._jdf.count())
  File "/Users/user1/Desktop/work/tools/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/Users/user1/opt/anaconda3/envs/work/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.PythonException: 
  An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user1/Desktop/code/models/model1/model1_utilities.py", line 3, in <module>
    import logger
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logger'
```

Logger is imported in the model1_utilities.py file. In order to access the packages I added the path to the packages in the main.py. I haven't done it in the model1_utilities.py (not sure if that's necessary). But I don't understand why this is the issue. I searched to see if there are problems with using modules and packages in pyspark jobs but couldn't find anything. Any leads will help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was not a pyspark error. The error appeared because I was not adding the path to packages in model1_utilities.py. Adding it fixed the error. Wasn't aware that python required the package path to be added in every file that wishes to use the package.